# Setting host and path in Apache 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect `http://oldsite.com/some/content` to `http://newsite.com/some/content` in .htaccess, but only that page (well, two pages, with the same idea).

From what I can see, 301 redirects don't take the host, only the path, in the first parameter, and

```
Redirect 301 /some/content http://newsite/some/content
```

isn't going to work, as oldsite.com is a ServerAlias of newsite.com (maybe not ideal, but that part is out of my hands), and it seems the rule above leads to a redirect loop.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I can't use a PHP solution as the redirect needs to execute before another rule further down in the same .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an env variable to identify the site, e.g.:

```
SetEnvIf default-site ^ site=new
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^oldsite\.com$ site=old
```

... and use mod_rewrite to perform a conditional redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:site} =old [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. I did't know about environment variables; I'll read up on those. +1 for teaching me something new. 

This is what worked in the end (I needed it to only work for two pages, and not execute for any other pages).

    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^oldsite\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/some/content.*
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R]` I guess I could just add the second RewriteCondition above to your code as well. Will explore that later tonight.